# nodejs + pm2 в режиме кластера нагрузка на один instance 100%

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, pdf, pm2

Backend api nodejs запущен в режиме кластера на 30 instance через определенное показатель cpu на одном instance переваливает за 100 процентов и api перестает работать, в pm2 list отображается, но по ссылке недоступно 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сервер на ubuntu 18.

UPD.
Причиной оказалась попытка разбить испорченный файл pdf, перед этим применялась библиотека pdf2json

```
    const pdfParser = new PDFParser();
    pdfParser.loadPDF(filePath);
    pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => {
        console.log(errData)
    });
    pdfParser.on('pdfParser_dataReady', pdfData => {
        console.log(pdfData)
    });
```

Всё это завернуто в Promise.
Если "pdfParser_dataReady" то происходит процедура разбиения и в конце resolve(), если "pdfParser_dataError", то reject()
Проблема в том. что нет ни того, ни другого.